# Timespan.Add() is not working

Tags: c#

Trying to add the time but when am trying to add 20:18:00+5:24:00 then the value is changing to 1:42:00 but i want the Value as 25:42:00

```
var sum = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:00");
var bd = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:00");
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
    if (dr["TotalTime"].ToString()==string.Empty) {
        bd =TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:00");
    } else {
        bd = TimeSpan.Parse(dr["TotalTime"].ToString());
    }

    sum = sum.Add(bd);
}
```

Comment: You will have to move to another planet...

Answer (score 3):

Did you check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? `TimeSpan` represents a time interval in *days*, hours, minutes, and seconds.

In all likelihood you're printing the wrong property, `Hours` instead of `TotalHours`.

Always read the documentation because that will verify your assumptions about how the class is supposed to be used.